# Как правильно написать условие для запроса Postgres UPDATE и Like

Tags: postgresql

Есть таблица, и мне нужно обновить данные в 3-м столбце в соответствии с условием. Если есть скобки, то вам нужно взять оттуда информацию, а если нет, то что находится в первом столбце. Поместите его туда, где нет информации в 3-й колонке. В большинстве случаев необходимо указать, где статус down или error

https://dbfiddle.uk/GgFft6cY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант (если я всё правильно понял):

```
UPDATE table_1
SET name_3 = 
  case
    when name_3 != '' THEN name_3
    when substring(name_1, '\((.*?)\)') is not null then substring(name_1, '\((.*?)\)')
    else name_1
  end
where  status in ('down','error');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE table_1
SET name_3 = 
    CASE
        WHEN name_3 != '' THEN name_3
        WHEN name_1 LIKE '%(%' THEN SUBSTRING(name_1 FROM '%(%' FOR ')')
        ELSE name_1
    END
WHERE status IN ('down', 'error');
```

Этот код обновляет столбец `name_3` следующим образом:

- Если столбец `name_3` не пустой, то он остается неизменным.
- Если столбец `name_1` содержит скобки, то в столбец `name_3` помещается текст, содержащийся между скобками.
- Если столбец `name_1` не содержит скобок, то в столбец `name_3` помещается значение столбца `name_1`.

Comment: Автор даже fiddle сделал - ну что мешало попробовать, а?

Comment: @polak228 не работает (
ERROR:  invalid regular expression: parentheses () not balanced